# How can I share my internet connection from windows to ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, networking, server, vpn, dhcp

Okay, so I have a mobile connection attached to my main pc (windows 8.1), the address range is 192.168.43.1 - 255 with the gateway being 192.168.43.1 and I want to share this to my Ubuntu server which is sitting in my LAN without an internet connection, my LAN address range is 10.1.1.1 - 255.

I have tried:

- Windows internet sharing but that wont work as there would be 2 dhcp servers on the LAN (not a good thing)
- A proxy, but for windows I can't find any software that is actually good, I'm quite new to squid so not very sure how to configure it to what I need it to do.
- VPN, this is also a nice option but again can't find any decent software for windows that can do it, if my main pc was windows server than it would be a different story.

If I could make the windows pc act as a gateway where the ubuntu server could just set a static IP pointing towards it without any dhcp server running, that would be great. But again I can't find any software to do this either.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I am having this exact same issue. My windows 8.1 is sharing its wifi internet connection with my Ubuntu desktop over a wired Ethernet connection.

I enabled in windows, the wifi internet sharing and added all the port forwarding services; but my ubuntu still isn't able to ping any networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually fixed this a while ago so I'll share my findings.

I haven't done exactly as my question asks but I found by using a Raspberry PI with a USB WiFi card as a router I could share my phone's internet connection to everything on my network.

I used this script: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/23 on my RPI, it can pretty much apply to any Linux distro though.

Comment: How are your devices on your network connecting to the linux computer?

Comment: Ethernet plus a wireless router in access point mode @William

Answer (score 0):

if the windows computer is the host for the internet connection, go to control panel and hit change adapter settings. click on the wifi connection, then while holding CONTROL, click the ethernet button, and right click and click BRIDGE CONNECTION. this should share the connection fron the windows computer to the Ubuntu device